# Multiple IF statements comparing 2 dataframes and populating dataframe based on result

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have 2 dataframes, one with a list of systems and versions and another with a list of all the systems/versions and whether they are obsolete, and I'm struggling to perform some sort of multi-if statement (including comparators) and populate the data in the first df with the data from the second.

The dataframes are;

```
>>> system_df
    ID    SIS_TYPE   EDITION   VERSION
0   SYS1      AMA     first       2
1   SYS2      DIR     first       10.3
2   SYS3      DIR     second      9
3   SYS4      ORA     first       7




>>> obsolete_df
    SIS_TYPE   EDITION   VERSION    OBSOLETE
0      AMA     first      2          YES
1      DIR     first      10         NO
2      DIR       *        9.1        NO
3      ORA     third      7          YES
4      ORA       *        9          NO
5      ORA       *        8          YES
```

What I'm trying to do is the following;

First I need to lookup the `SIS_TYPE` in obsolet_df, then I want to check the `EDITION` for a match, but if there is not match in `EDITION` it should match with the asterisk. After finding a match with both these columns I then want to check the `VERSION` column for *one* of these three things;

- a direct match
- a partial match using a regex to compare the first number (9.1 = 9)
- if none of the above then check the value of the next highest version (checking 9 against 10, 11 etc.)

Final step would be to add the `OBSOLETE` value into the system_df if all of these conditions are satisfied.

So the desired result would be something like;

```
>>> final_df
    ID    SIS_TYPE   EDITION   VERSION    OBSOLETE
0   SYS1      AMA     first      2          YES
1   SYS2      DIR     first      10         NO
2   SYS3      DIR       *        9.1        NO
3   SYS4      ORA     third      8          YES
```

I've tried many combinations of `.loc`, `merge` and `join` but I cannot get the dataframe how I need it.

EDIT: I've tried with the following however it's too slow for the quantity of entries in the real dataframe:

```
        l = []
        for s_row in system_df.itertuples():
            for o_row in obsolete_df.loc[obsolete_df['SUBSYSTEM_TYPE'] == s_row[26]].itertuples():
                if s_row[28] == o_row[2]:
                    l.append((s_row[28], s_row[2]))
                elif o_row[2] == '*':
                    l.append((s_row[28], s_row[2]))
```

Comment: You have 4 entries in system_df. Why do you have 5 in final_df ?. In case you want to merge system_df and obsolete_df then final_df should have more than 5 rows... Why do you have two rows with index 4 in obsolete_df ?

Comment: @joaquin because the obsolete_df contains repeated information (on SIS_TYPE level). This is the pridicament I have, is that it is more of a conditional lookup rather than a merge. The row index was a typo which I've corrected.

Comment: I am not talking about columns, but rows. Is it only one row added to final_df relative to system_df (SYS5) after merging ? What about ORA vs 9 in obsolete_df ?  Just trying to understand what is the actual result df you want

Comment: Yes sorry, it was a typo on my part. There should be no added rows, just populating the the new column `OBSOLETE` within the system_df, given the conditional lookups through columns `SIS_TYPE`, `EDITION` and `VERSION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like:

```
l = []
for i in range(len(obsolete_df)):
    s_row = system_df[i]
    o_row = obsolete_df[i]
    if s_row[2] == o_row[1]: # compare SIS_TYPE
        if s_row[2] == o_row[1] or o_row[1] == '*': # compare EDITION
            l.append((s_row[1], s_row[2], ...))
```

It hasn't all needed validations, but it will be easy to add them. Sorry, I didn't test it!

Comment: No problem and thanks! I really just needed a starting place i will play around with this and see how I get on

Comment: I tried with the following;

`l = []`

`for s_row in self.final_df.itertuples():`

            `for o_row in` 
`self.obsolete_dataframe.loc[self.obsolete_dataframe['SUBSYSTEM_TYPE'] ==` 
`s_row[26]].itertuples():`

                `if s_row[28] == o_row[2]:  # compare EDITION`

                    `l.append((s_row[28], s_row[2]))`

                `elif o_row[2] == '*':`

                    `l.append((s_row[28], s_row[2]))`

However it took a very, very long time, the df has around 300k entries so will have to search for something more optimised. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks Greg, I've worked on it using your suggestion as a starting point and it works well. I've posted my own answer as reference if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on greg's answer, looping through the rows of both tables and directly comparing the values seems to work fine. Final code used;

```
#Iterating through each row in system_df
for s_row in system_df.itertuples():
        #Iterating through each row in obsolete_df if the SIS_TYPE matches
        for o_row in obsolete_df.loc[obsolete_df['SIS_TYPE'] == s_row[2]].itertuples():

            #Comparing Editions and Versions
            if s_row[3] == o_row[2] and s_row[4] == o_row[3]:
                #Updating the system_df with new values if match
                system_df.at[s_row.Index, 'OBSOLETE'] = o_row[4]

            #Else if use'*' for Edition and compare Versions
            elif o_row[2] == '*' and s_row[4] == o_row[3]:
                system_df.at[s_row.Index, 'OBSOLETE'] = o_row[4]
```